# How to Print path and final distance matrix of Bellman Ford using c?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, bellman-ford

I was trying to implement **Bellman-Ford** but that is not running I tried all methods that I know but I was not able to print paths and distance Matrix in C. Can anyone please give me solution of this?

```
    #include
    #include
    #include
    typedef struct edge
    {
        int s,d,w;
        struct edge *next;
    }Edge;
    typedef struct graph
    {
        int V,E;
        Edge *e;
    }graph;
    graph* createGraph(int v,int e)
    {
        graph* g=(graph*)malloc(sizeof(graph));
        g->V=v;
        g->E=e;
        g->e=(Edge*)malloc(sizeof(Edge)*e);
        return g;
    }
    void bellMan(graph *g,int src)
    {
        int v=g->V;
        int e=g->E;
        int dist[v],path[v];
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;ie[j].s;
                int y=g->e[j].d;
                int w=g->e[j].w;
                if(dist[x]!=INT_MAX && dist[x]+we[i].s;
            int y=g->e[i].d;
            int w=g->e[i].w;
            if(dist[x]!=INT_MAX && dist[x]+we[i].s,&g->e[i].d,&g->e[i].w);
        printf("Enter starting vertex:");
        scanf("%d",&s);
        bellMan(g,s);
        return 0;
    }
```

Please help me how to print path and Distance Matrix(in which distance of one node to another node is specified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of answer you hope to receive. Your question is very unclear.

But here what you should do:

1) Check if your matrix represents the graph correctly. Make sure you get the trick.

2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ttezuzs39nk watch this MIT lecture.

3) Try other algorithms. I suggest Dijkstra, it is simpler in my point of view.

Comment: I know how to use Dijkstra algorithm. I was trying to implement Bellman-Ford but my code in not printing path correctly and final distance Matrix

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to be recursive. Did you intend this function to call itself?

Comment: You also have a return here, but your function does not need to return any value

Comment: I'm glad you did!